# Can't fetch nested mongoose queries using populate in graphQL

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

I'm wiring up a graphQL backend with mongoose and I am having trouble with some of the conventions of mongoose for a nested query. If I have the following field in the root query:

```
course: {
  type: CourseType,
  args: { id: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID) } },
  resolve(parentValue, { id }) {
    return Course.findById(id);
  },
},
```

A Course Type of this:

```
const CourseType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'CourseType',
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLID },
    sections: {
      type: new GraphQLList(SectionType),
      resolve(parentValue) {
        return Course.findSections(parentValue._id);
      }
    }
  }),
});
```

And my model looks like this:

```
const CourseSchema = new Schema({
  _id: { type: String },
  sections: [{
    type: Schema.Types.String,
    ref: 'Section'
  }],
});

CourseSchema.statics.findSections = function(id) {
  return this.findById(id)
    .populate('Sections')
    .then(course => {
      return course.sections
    });
}

mongoose.model('Course', CourseSchema, 'Courses');

const SectionSchema = new Schema({
  _id: { type: String },
  course: {
    type: Schema.Types.String,
    ref: 'Course',
  },
});

mongoose.model('Section', SectionSchema, 'Sections');
```

I would expect that I could run a query like this:

```
query {
 course(id: "4Zpm8zrZYqdbr2i4t") {
  id
  sections {
    id
  }
 }
}
```

And I should get back a given course with all of its sections. The sections come back as an empty array while the course comes back as expected. I can tell that if I look in the findSections method that it has the proper id, but `populate` doesn't seem to fetch the sections.

I have a feeling that I'm running into some issue with how mongoose uses its conventions for how to name stuff but I can't for the life of me figure out what is going on. Here is what my mongoDB looks like:

```
MongoDB:
Courses: { _id: "4Zpm8zrZYqdbr2i4t" }
Sections: { _id: "00000000000000000", courseId: "4Zpm8zrZYqdbr2i4t" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that does not look correct. You want to populate for the path sections but the string is in capital letter. See the [docu](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate).

So it should look like this:

```js
CourseSchema.statics.findSections = function(id) {
  return this.findById(id)
    .populate('sections') // lower case
    .then(course => {
      return course.sections
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks that did it! I didn't realize that my courses needs an array of all the sections AND it isn't enough to have all my sections have a courseId.

Comment: Just as a final question to really make sure I understand it- would it be possibly to have a query for Section.findById in your code block above so that we can search a child collection for ids that match the parent we are querying for?

Comment: Im not perfectly sure what you mean. But maybe you mean the [in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in) functionality of the mongoDB.

Comment: Sorry I'll try once more: 1 course has many sections. Each section has a courseId. Can I find out the sections a course has without saving the sections:[sectionId1, sectionId2...] in course? Instead I would search the sections collection for all { courseId=course._id } so go the other way?

Comment: Sure just use `find`. E.G. `SectionModel.find({"course_id": <given course id>}, (error, sections) => { // do something})`. But i suggest you let it like this because i think it is one of the big advantages of mongoDB and what if you want to add a section to different courses?